# Ethereum downloading blocks stuck

Tags: wallets, ethereum-wallet-dapp

I don't know much about investing as i am still new to this. I use ethereum node Geth 1.7.2. I bought a certain percentage of ethereum without letting it sync or download the blocks first (though I have confirmed that I received ether online). What do I do now as the downloading is stuck with only 230 blocks left. As I do not want to do anything that would end up in my wallet information being lost.
Thank you

Comment: Thank you for letting me know, one final question will i lose any ethereum wallet data if i download parity?

Answer (score -1):

Probably you have a PC with a HDD. Geth and Mist should run on an SSD. If you just want desktop wallet and PC with a HDD, you should try Parity - it syncs fast and works fine on HDD computers. If you want an online wallet, try [MyEtherWallet](https://www.myetherwallet.com).